# Solving hypersurface integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, surface-integrals

Can you help me to compute the following integral over a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^4$?

$$\int_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2 = 1} ||x||^{-2s} d\mu$$

So here we have
$$||x||^2 := x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2.$$

The measure $d\mu$ is the inherited Lebesgue messure from $\mathbb R^4$. So how do I proceed? Parametrize the hypersurface and then use appropriate formulas involving the first fundamental form?

I'm not only interested in the value of the integral but also for which $s \in \mathbb C$ it exists. I would guess for ${\rm Re}(s)>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can follow the process you proposed: parametrize the surface, calculate the hypervolume form, then integrate.

### The parametrization

*I'll include some of my thought process.*  Let the hypersurface be called $S$.  Intersecting $S$ with the planes $x_3=h$ and $x_4 = k$ gives a circle with equation $x_1^2 +x_2^2 = 1 + h^2 + k^2$.  Intersecting with planes $x_1 = h$ and $x_2 = k$ gives a circle with equation $x_3^2 + x_4^2 = h^2+k^2 - 1$.  And intersecting with the plane $x_2 = x_4 = 0$ gives a hyperbola $x_1^2-x_3^2 = 1$.  So I thought about parametrizing the two circles and the hyperbola separately.

I know that to parametrize a circle of radius $r$ in the $xy$-plane, $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin\theta$ will work.  We can do this in the $x_1x_2$-plane, and again in the $x_3x_4$-plane.  The two radii
lie on the hyperbola $r_1^2-r_2^2=1$.  There are many ways to parametrize the hyperbola; I chose $\psi \mapsto (\sec\psi,\tan\psi)$ since I already had trigonometric functions of the other coordinates.  I suppose $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ would also work, and might be a bit cleaner.

Based on this, we see that the coordinate functions
\begin{align*}
    x_1 &= \sec\psi \cos\theta \\
    x_2 &= \sec\psi \sin\theta \\
    x_3 &= \tan\psi \cos\phi \\
    x_4 &= \tan\psi \sin\phi
\end{align*}
land in $S$.  We still need to know the domain on which this function is bijective.

Given $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in S$, let $r_1 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $r_2 = \sqrt{x_3^2 + x_4^2}$. Then both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are nonnegative, and $r_1^2-r_2^2 = 1$.  So there exists a unique $\psi$ with $0 \leq \psi < \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $r_1 = \sec\psi$ and $r_2 = \tan\psi$.

Since $r_1^2-r_2^2 =1$, $r_1 > 0$, and so there exists a unique $\theta$ such that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ and
$$
    \cos\theta = \frac{x_1}{r_1}
    \qquad
    \sin\theta = \frac{x_2}{r_1}
$$
Now $r_2 > 0$ is not guaranteed, but if it is true, there exists a unique $\phi$ such that
$$
    \cos\phi  = \frac{x_3}{r_2}
    \qquad
    \sin\phi  = \frac{x_4}{r_2}
$$

So if we restrict to the intervals $-\pi \leq \theta\leq \pi$, $-\pi\leq\phi\leq\pi$, $0 \leq \psi < \frac{\pi}{2}$, the mapping will be surjective, and only fail to be injective on the domain's boundary.  This will be good enough.

### The integrand

The matrix of partial derivatives of this parametrization is:
$$
   J = \frac{\partial(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}{\partial(\psi,\theta,\phi)}
     = \begin{bmatrix}
           \sec\psi\tan\psi\cos\theta
                & \sec\psi\tan\psi\sin\theta
                    & \sec^2\psi \cos\phi
                         & \sec^2\psi \sin\phi \\
           -\sec\psi\sin\theta
                & \sec\psi\cos\theta & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & -\tan\psi\sin\phi & \tan\psi\cos\phi
       \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
In these coordinates, $dS = \sqrt{\det J^TJ}\,d\psi\,d\theta\,d\phi$. Since
$$
    J^TJ = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sec^2\psi\tan^2\psi + \sec^4\psi & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \sec^2\psi & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \tan^2\psi \end{bmatrix}
$$
So
$$
    dS = \sec^2 \psi \tan \psi \sqrt{\sec^2\psi + \tan^2 \psi}\,d\psi\,d\theta\,d\phi
$$
($\tan\psi \geq 0$ since $0 \leq \psi < π/2$.)
In these coordinates, the function to be integrated is:
\begin{align*} 
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) &= \left\Vert x \right\Vert^{-2s}
    \\&= \left[\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2\right)^{1/2}\right]^{-2s}
    \\&= \left(\sec^2\psi + \tan^2\psi\right)^{-s}
\end{align*}

### The integral

Putting these together, we see that:
\begin{align*}
    I &= \iiint_S f\,dS
    \\&= \int_{-π}^π \int_{-π}^π \int_0^{π/2} \sec^2\psi \tan \psi  \left(\sec^2\psi + \tan^2\psi\right)^{1/2-s} \,d\psi\,d\theta\,d\phi
    \\&= 4π^2 \int_0^{π/2} \sec^2\psi \tan \psi  \left(\sec^2\psi + \tan^2\psi\right)^{1/2-s} \,d\psi
\end{align*}
Let $v = \sec^2\psi + \tan^2 \psi$, so that $dv = 4\tan \psi \sec^2\psi\,d\psi$.  Then
$$
    I = π^2\int_1^\infty v^{1/2-s}\,dv
$$
This converges if $\Re(s) > \frac{3}{2}$.  In that case,
$$
    I = -\frac{π^2}{\frac{3}{2} - s} = \frac{2π^2}{2s-3}
$$

Comment: Your parametrization covers the surface twice, and the integral is positive, so $I = 2 \pi^2/(2 s - 3)$.

Comment: Oh, I see you're right about the sign.  I have to think more about the double covering.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for your great answer. It's quite easy to check for your parametrization that it actually lands in my hypersurface. But how do you see that the map is injective and surjective? And how did you come up with the parametrization?

Comment: I went through everything now and also think that the parametrization covers the surface twice. Simply let $0\le \psi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. This should be enough.

Comment: To make the double cover more precise: I think for $(\psi,\theta,\phi)$ and $(-\psi,\theta,\phi+\pi)$ you should get the point on the surface.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I figured out the very same thing a minute ago! I'm in the process of rewriting the answer to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me much. I was able to solve my open questions by myself. In particular how to come up with the parametrization and why it works. The first moment I saw your answer it was quite mysterious to me but then I understood.